# Have internet provided from one line, and local network provided to another

Tags: linux, networking, plex

I'm having a bit of an issue with my home server running [Unraid](https://unraid.net/). I'm wondering if this is possible.

I'm currently having a business line put into the house to run services that I provide to people as a bit of a hobby. I run these services on Unraid through Docker containers. I am however limited to 50mbps on the upload, which im having issues with currently.

Is there a way to have my current home network, connected to my Unraid via a 2nd Ethernet port from a separate NIC, have local play for things like [Plex TV](https://www.plex.tv/) through that port, and all services being provided outside of the local network through the business line?

[image: Networking Idea]

Comment: my first thought is that if you have few enough devices to manually configure them, than this is pretty simple. set the default gateway to the home devices to point to the residential router, and have your unraid systems point their default gateway to the business router. then if everything in on the same LAN, your concerns about internal use of the servers is addressed as well. If you have too many systems to manually configure you will have to put a router in a define two networks using DHCP to configure each realms devices. with an enterprise router its easy to allow the LANs to talk.

Comment: the big complication most people face is they try to use a residential grade internet access router in the middle of their network. that's not what they are for, so you have to struggle with the default behavior to allow bi-directional comms. if you use an enterprise router, its pretty simple to let the LANs communicate. if you do use an internet access router, you can try putting the WAN side on the business LAN, so that devices from the Home LAN can access the servers (though the servers will not be able to reach the Home LAN unless responding to a request, without port forwarding).

Comment: Running 2 networks in parallel would be the 'easy' way, either via actually physically seperate networks, or vlans

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I'm assuming running the 2 networks in parallel would be the way I've crudely displayed above? Or would this take form in another way?

Comment: Ah! I missed that.  Essentially that should work, yeah. Have the unraid connected to 'both' networks, and make sure they're on different subnets more or less.

Comment: Oh and appropriate firewall rules so people not on the local net can't access your 'internal' applications

Comment: Ah sweet, cheers! Ill give that a go soon and will report back on whether it works or not